# Flink DataSet program does not produce output

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to write the result of a DataSet API program into a file using `DataSet.writeAsText("file:///path/to/my/file")`.

However, the program does not produce any output. The output file is not created either. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you provide more detail and paste a code snippet? Without further information it is not possible to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you execute the job, i.e., call `ExecutionEnvironment.execute()`?

```
// get execution environment
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

// Specify your program ...
DataSet<X> ds1 = env...
DataSet<Y> ds2 = ds1.map(...)...
ds2.writeAsText(...);

// execute the program
env.execute();
```